Variant of Leray-Hirsch for complex-oriented cohomology theory
I am interested in a variant of the Leray-Hirsch theorem. Let $\mathbb{E}^*$ be a complex-oriented cohomology theory and let $\mathbb{E}_*$ the coefficient ring. Suppose that $F \xrightarrow{i} P \to B$ is a fiber bundle with $F,P,B$ finite CW complexes. I assume that $B$ has only even dimensional cells
(though I expect the claim to be true more generally). Suppose I have a splitting $\mathbb{E}^*(F) \to \mathbb{E}^*(P)$ of the restriction $i^*: \mathbb{E}^*(P) \to \mathbb{E}^*(F).$
Is the resulting map $$\mathbb{E}^*(F)\otimes_{\mathbb{E}_{*}}\mathbb{E}^*(B) \to \mathbb{E}^*(P) $$ an isomorphism? I suspect that if this is true, it can be proven with standard spectral sequence arguments. Is there a reference for the result in this form?

It's proved on pg. 430 of tom Dieck's book that this is an isomorphism of left $E^*(B)$-modules (it is generally not an algebra isomorphism).

@Tyrone I do not wish to assume the cohomology of the fiber is free over $\mathbb{E}_*$.

You definitely need some flatness assumption on the cohomology of $F$ or $B$. If $E$ is complex orientable, evenness of the cells of $B$ probably saves you there, but without assumptions on $E$ there should be counterexamples even with trivial fiber bundles $F\times B$ (for example with $E=\mathbb{S}$)

@AchimKrause I understand your point. Even in my restrictive case, to get $E^(B)$ to be free over $E_$, I need an assumption.  I am happy to assume complex orientable as well and have adjusted the question. How should the argument go then?

I'm not sure about a reference, but  the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence for a fibration proves this theorem. You need to know that $E^q(P)$ surjects onto $H^0(B,E^q(F))$ which your assumption buys you. If you know that  $E_2^{p,q}=H^P(B,E^q(F)) \cong H^p(B,E^) \otimes_{E^} H^q(F,E^)=E_2^{p,0} \otimes E_2^{0,q}$ [ For example if the the cohomology of the fiber is free as an $E^$ module, but maybe Achim's rmk is ok] then the spectral sequence collapsing on the second page ($d_2=0$ on $E^{p,0}$) proves the claim. I saw your last comment but this is the SS argument I know

Sorry if you were already aware of this proof. I don't know maybe someone smarter can cook up the weakest conditions for (something like) the second fact to hold and then this argument works
